# Change character string based on order of appearance

Tags: r, excel, string, replace, position

I have an excel sheet with over 600 cells where the data in each cell is something like:

```
 "Text blah blah {X}, text blah blah {X}"
```

Is there a way (in excel or R), to systematically rename the X's in each cell so that they have unique names. i.e:

```
        Column 1
Row 1 : "Text blah blah {X1}, text blah blah {X2}"
Row 2 : "Text different {X1}, text new {X2}"
Row 2 : "Text Other {X1}, new text {X2}, other text {X3}"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a better way to do this, but this is simple to understand and it works. It relies on the fact that `str_replace` replaces only the first match in each string.

```
z = "Text blah blah {X}, text blah blah {X}"

library(stringr)
n = max(str_count(z, fixed("{X}")))

for(i in 1:n) {
  z = str_replace(z, pattern = fixed("{X}"), replacement = paste0("{X", i, "}"))
}

z
# [1] "Text blah blah {X1}, text blah blah {X2}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found an excel way of doing it too using substitute too:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, "{X}", "{X1}",1)
```